# Add pair in a tuple to each item in a list

Tags: python

With just basic Python and no other libraries, how can I add a value `(1, 0)`
to each item of a list containing items:

```
[(0, 0)]
[(0, 1)]
[(0, 2)]
[(0, 3)]
```

Such that if the initial row, starting with `[(0, 0)]`, a new list of items is created having the elements

```
[(0, 0)], [(1, 0)], [(2, 0)], [(3, 0)]
```

i.e. `[(0,0)]` plus the value `(1, 0)`?

Comment: Its not very clear what your input data is. What you show is a series of lists. How do these relate to anything? If you could show come input data and expected output and ensure your description makes the relationship between them clear it would be a huge help.

Comment: agreed, what does the list you show have to do with anything?

Comment: ie How to add two ordered pairs as x,y coordinates, so how to get the coordinates out of the list, then access the x and y separately, add some x y off sets to each component, then package the new coordinates and shove them into a list.

Comment: Tuples are a poor choice if you want to modify the points - List contents can be directly  modified.  You may want to search for Vector implementations

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list = [[(0, 0)],[(0, 1)],[(0, 2)],[(0, 3)]]
item_to_add = [(1,0)]
#way 1 use for loop
for item in my_list:
    item.append(item_to_add)
print my_list

my_list = [[(0, 0)],[(0, 1)],[(0, 2)],[(0, 3)]]
# way 2 use list comprehension
[item.append(item_to_add) for item in my_list]
print my_list
```

Comment: `append()` returns `None`, therefore your list comprehension results in a list full of `None`, I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't want to append (1,0), I want to add 1 to 0 and 0 to 0 to yield (1,0), then repeat until I have (0,0),(1,0), (2,0),(3,0). That would be 1 row in a grid with (0,0) being the origin.

Comment: I don't want to append (1,0), I want to add 1 to 0 and 0 to 0 to yield (1,0), then repeat until I have (0,0),(1,0), (2,0),(3,0). That would be 1 row in a grid with (0,0) being the origin. The next row would be (0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1). The pairs in my_list represent column and rows, and the item to add is an offset to the grid used to generate coordinates for a row or column with an item in the list being the initial cell.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GzrnXxo5zE&list=PLPk0UGJMykbHQNLmxIxYwRNYctTNMtG-j&index=15 see 6:00 to 9:13